# Calculating a work rate in Python

Tags: python

If I had the variables: hours, minutes, and seconds respectively representing the number of hours of work, the number of minutes of work, and the number of seconds of work, how would I calculate the salary of the rate, x

this is what I have:

```
rate = (hours*x) + (minutes*x)*0.1 + (seconds*x)*0.01
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Im assuming it's probably a mess up in the formula, but I'm not sure what it is

Comment: Is `x` a string, by any chance?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the variables?

Comment: Am I losing my mind? A minute is not a tenth of an hour, and a second is not a tenth of a minute.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: It's not homework. Im on Christmas break right now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have very little experience in Python but I'll take a stab at it. You are trying to multiply a number to a non-number. Assuming the string `x` "represents" a valid number, you can convert it to a `float` or an `int`. Try this instead:

```
x = float(x);
rate = (hours * x) + (minutes * x * (1.0/60)) + (seconds * x * (1.0/3600))
```

Answer (score 4):

Either `minutes` or `x` is *not* an integer; most likely you have a string there instead:

```
>>> minutes = 5
>>> x = '10'
>>> minutes * x
'1010101010'
>>> (minutes * x) * 0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Make sure your inputs are all numbers.

Note that your hourly-rate formula doesn't seem quite correct; I'd calculate that as:

```
rate = (hours + (minutes / 60.0) + (seconds / 3600.0)) * x
```

as there are 60 minutes in an hour, and 3600 seconds.

Comment: what if I have a number that has a decimal. What should I use?

Comment: You can convert a string with a decimal to a floating point number with `float()`.